# Find the image of L under $e^z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let L = $\{(x,y): y = 2x\}$. Find the image of L under $e^z$. Also sketch the image.

I am really confused about all of this but here is my attempt. Say we are mapping from the z-plane to the w-plane.

In the z-plane, we are taking all points on the line y = 2x. We want to put each point through the transformation $e^z = e^{x+iy}$ (if we let z = x + iy) that maps to the w-plane.

Since y = 2x, we get $e^z = e^{x+iy} = e^{x + i{x \over 2}} = e^xe^{i{x \over 2}}$. This is equivalent to

$e^x(cos({x \over 2})+isin({x \over 2}))$.

$=e^xcos({x \over 2})+ie^xsin({x \over 2})$

$= u + iv$ (so we have the u-coordinate and v-coordinate).

I have no clue if this is the image, and I also don't know how to draw this. Do I just start plugging in points?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right. The image is the set $\{ e^x (\cos(x/2) + i \sin(x/2)) \colon x \in \mathbf{R} \}$ in the $w$ plane. To draw it, note that without the factor $e^x$ you would have the point $w=\cos(x/2) + i \sin(x/2)$ which moves counterclockwise around the unit circle as $x$ increases. Multiplying this by the real number $e^x$ has the effect of increasing the radius (i.e., the distance from the origin to $w$) as $x$ increases. This means that you get a spiral instead of a circle. (As $x \to -\infty$, the spiral approaches the origin in the $w$ plane, and as $x \to +\infty$, it grows without bound.)

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates, the equation becomes $\theta = \pm \arctan 2$,
and $\exp (re^{i\theta})  =e^{r\cos \theta} e^{ri\sin \theta} $
The constrain $\sin\theta/\cos\theta = 2$ writes with the coordinates of the image:
$$
R = e^{r\cos\theta}
\\
\Theta = r\sin\theta
\\
\frac \Theta {\log R}= 2 \iff R = \exp\frac\Theta2
$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I quite understand what you're getting at.

Where did the $\theta$ come from and why did you do what you did with exp?

Comment: the $\theta$ is from the polar coordinates. in polar coordinates, $y/x =2 \iff \sin\theta / \cos\theta = 2$